# How to check a specific range value is filled in SQL with Window functions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am working on a project in which we should evaluate suppliers and in this database I have this table `EvaluationGrade`:

```
+------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| Id   | EvaluationMethodId  | FromScore  | ToScore   |                       
+------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 1    |       2             |     1      |    20     |
| 2    |       2             |     21     |    50     |
| 3    |       2             |     51     |    70     |
| 4    |       2             |     71     |    100    |
| 5    |       3             |     1      |    20     |
| 6    |       3             |     31     |    40     |
+------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

This table categorize scores and I am gonna be sure for `EvaluationMethodId=2` scope values fill 1 to 100 (just like sample above).

I am looking for something like this:

```
+---------------------+------------+
| EvaluationMethodId  |    Sum     |                      
+---------------------+------------+
|       2             |     100    |
|       3             |     30     |
+---------------------+------------+
```

This is the way I attempted:

```
WITH myUpdate
AS (SELECT emg.Id,emg.EvaluationMethodId,
           SUM(emg.ToGrade - emg.FromGrade) + 1 AS SumScope
    FROM generalsup.EvaluationMethodGrading emg
    GROUP BY emg.Id,emg.EvaluationMethodId)
SELECT myUpdate.EvaluationMethodId, SUM(myUpdate.SumScope) AS SumScopeAll
FROM myUpdate
GROUP BY myUpdate.EvaluationMethodId;
```

But I use window function that put less overhead on server.

Comment: please show your attempt query

Comment: @Squirrel - I put my query

Comment: Is there a case of overlaps, like FromScore =1, ToScore = 20 and FromScore =10, ToScore = 30 for the same EvaluationMethodId?

Comment: @forpas- No, overlap checked before insert, so there is no overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no case of overlaps in the scores, you can do it with `group by EvaluationMethodId` and `sum()`:

```
select EvaluationMethodId, sum(ToScore - FromScore + 1) [Sum]
from EvaluationMethodGrading 
group by EvaluationMethodId
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f38ddf5c4c9a35681b4a94b371369b4c).
Results:

```
> EvaluationMethodId | Sum
> -----------------: | --:
>                  2 | 100
>                  3 |  30
```

Comment: @forpas- Changing database manually, is there any way to change this script to cover overlapping scope?